# Set Cookie Path

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a javascript cookie which works although I have pages in different directories. The cookie set on the default page has a path "/" while the cookie set in another directory has a path "/example"

I know many people have asked this many times but I can't do it by myself. I made a cookie code that actually works from the past three months. I don't want to mess it up. Can anyone help me add a set path "/" to my cookie code? Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

    function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue) {
     var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
    var nDays=365
     expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
     document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
             + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indicate the path by adding the following to the end of the cookie string in function "SetCookie":

```
"; path=/";
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#doccookie

Comment: Your code works but it makes two cookies now. One with a path "/", which I wanted, but also one with a path "/example". I could I remove the second cookie from being made?

Comment: Never mind, I added your code to the same line and now everything works perfectly.    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";   Thank you.