# How do I add a path to a cookie function?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am having some trouble adding the path of "/" to my cookie, which is set with a function.

```
function WriteCookie(){
if(document.part1.pn1.value==""){
    return;
    }

        var cookievalue=escape(document.part1.pn1.value) + ";";
        document.cookie="partnumber1=" + cookievalue;
```

I'm sure it is a very simple answer, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried something like:

```
    function WriteCookie(){
    if(document.part1.pn1.value==""){
        return;
        }

            var cookievalue=escape(document.part1.pn1.value) + ";";
            document.cookie="partnumber1=" + cookievalue + path=/;
```

But clearly this is not correct.

Comment: MDN's cookie code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework look at line 56 where they set the cookie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146984/set-cookie-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer you need:

```
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
```

If you set path=/ the cookie is available for the whole domain. Otherwise, your cookie is saved just for the current page you can't access it on another page.

For more info read- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html - review the Domain and path section